# convert a tuple of tuples into bytes in python

Tags: python, sockets, type-conversion, blender

I'm making a video game in upbge (which for this aspect is basically python) but to send the info between sockets it needs to be in bytes but i only found a way to do it turning it into a string, (because the list get's created with the game (i have a script that once a new entity appears it get's added to the list in the form of (Player-entity|data) but i want the data to variate between entities and i ran out of symbols to use to split it into lists so i'm trying to send the data as a list to be able to simply check it's components, but as it's a list inside of a list (and sometimes more) the bytearray won't work (at least i can't figure out how to make it work)

I'm unsure of how to summarize the code, but this is the code that I have now to generate that info

```
import socket

mi_socket = socket.socket()
mi_socket.bind(('127.0.0.1',55555))
mi_socket.listen()

TP = 0 #Total players
AP = 0 #Actual player
PL = ["host"] #Player List
AE = 0 #Actual entity
TE = 0 #Total entities
EL = ["|PlayerEntity$[Data]|"] #Entity list

PI = [] #Player Intel (Player name, Total Players, Player Code) (apartado uno en las comunicaciones)
order = None #Variable reservada para guardar comandos u identificaciones (ej: nombre de la entidad) en las comunicaciones
content = None #Variable reservada para almacenar la información recibida

incoming = 0 #Variable reservada para analizar el mensaje recibido de entrada

def login():
    global AP
    global TP
    global PL
    PJ = str(incoming).split("$")[1] #incoming Player
    if AP <= TP:
        if PJ!=str(PL[int(AP)]): #Nombre jugador que se conecta
            AP+=1
            login()
            pass
        else:
            identity()
        pass
    if AP > TP:
        PL.append(str("Player" + str(AP))) #Agregar jugador a la lista
        TP = int(AP)

def identity(): #identifica de qué se trata la orden para responder en consecuencia, si se trata de entidad anota tmb la entidad en la lista
    global TE
    global AE
    global EL
    global AP
    global PL
    PJ = str(incoming).split("$")[1]  # incoming Player
    PE = str(incoming).split("$")[2]  # incoming entity
    if AE <= TE:
        # Si nombre de jugador|nombre de objeto no és EL[AE]([1]|[2])
        if str(str(PL[AP])+"-"+str(PE)) != str(str(EL[AE]).split("|")[1]).split("$")[0]:
            AE+=1
            identity()
            pass
        else:
            EL[AE] = "|"+PL[AP]+"-"+PE+"$"+str(incoming).split("$")[3]+"|"
    if AE > TE:
        EL.append("|"+PL[AP]+"-"+PE+"$"+str(incoming).split("$")[3]+"|")
        TE = int(AE)

def main():
    global AP
    global AE
    global TE
    global  incoming
    conexion, ip = mi_socket.accept()
    incoming = conexion.recv(1024)
    login()
    conexion.send(str("#"+str(PL[AP])+"#"+str(EL[1:TE+1])+"#").encode())
    AP=0
    AE=0
    conexion.close()

while True:
    main()
```

Comment: Try [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/pickle.html).  From the documentation, "“Pickling” is the process whereby a Python object hierarchy is converted into a byte stream, and “unpickling” is the inverse operation, whereby a byte stream (from a binary file or bytes-like object) is converted back into an object hierarchy".  [Here](https://pythonprogramming.net/pickle-objects-sockets-tutorial-python-3/) is an example using pickle and sockets.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's just what i needed, and also thanks to learning it i learned how to use dictionaries better so basically you saved me from literal pages of innecesary scripts XD